# FUNCTION INDEX + MATCH + OFFSET alternate solution

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-365

good day

In the attached file I have an Excel sheet in which I am performing some searches according to certain criteria such as month (cell I4) and Salesperson (I12).
The question is that for the first search (cell I8), taking into account the month (I4), Total Sales (I6) and Max. individual sale (I7), I want to know the name of the salesman who made them (cell I8). To make this possible I have applied several functions between INDEX+MATCH+OFFSET, but I find them a bit confusing because in case I need to add more columns to the data matrix, I have to modify their arguments.

The same happens with the result obtained in cell (I16).

Is it possible to apply another type of formula that allows me to simplify or automate in a better way the results obtained in cells I8 and I16, for example using other functions such as VLOOKUP+MATCH or INDEX+MATCH?

I appreciate your valuable collaboration!

PST. I am using Excel 365 version

[attached file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SrWaojIBZcGEz90PyG7c2JKKwmNqbTEa/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Please also include screenshot and formula in your question. Many people doesn't like to open shared files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your shared sample, I get the result of I8 is "Sue".

If you have Excel for Microsoft 365 apps with newer versions, please enter the formula `=XLOOKUP(I7,OFFSET($B$1:$F$1,$I$4,0,1,),B1:F1)` in cell I8.

Then enter the formula `=XLOOKUP(I15,OFFSET($A$2:$A$13,0,MATCH(I12,B1:F1,),12,),A2:A13)` in cell I16.

[image]

But if there are multiple repeated maximum values in one row or column, the formula will be problematic.

Comment: Thank you very much for your valuable information, it has been very useful!